# Гипотеза Коллатца Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, функции

Доброго времени суток. Задача написать функцию, принимающую на ввод строку с целым числом. Если число четное - разделить на 2. Если нечетное - умножить на 3 и прибавить 1. С полученным результатом проделать те же процедуры, в зависимости от четности, конечно. На выходе должна быть строка с последовательностью всех чисел-результатов, разделенных пробелом. Входное число > 0. Крайнее число в последовательности - 1.
Вот что у меня получилось:

```
def col(n):
sp = [n]
if n < 1:
   return []
while n > 1:
   if n % 2 == 0:
     n = n // 2
   else:
     n = 3 * n + 1 
   sp.append(n)
for i in sp:
    print(i, end = ' ')
```

Интерпретатор выводит все верно (для числа 17 например):

```
17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

Но в задачнике тест не проходит.

https://stepik.org/lesson/Collatz-conjecture-or-the-3n-+-1-problem-21305/step/1?adaptive=true&unit=5105
Ссылка на задачу. Что я сделал не так? Я предполагаю, что проблема с выводом.

```
return ' '.join(sp)
```

я сначала делал вместо принта, но в списке числа, а не строки. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нет доступа к задачнику

Comment: попробуйте авторизоваться через ВК, например. Честно говоря, не в первый раз сталкиваюсь с проблемами в их тестах, но выбирать не приходится.

Comment: Вы можете генератор вместо списка использовать, [пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/1b147fdeb9d66a599f3b60925fa3d43e)

Comment: к моему стыду, еще плохо умею.

Answer (score 2):

Решение

```
def col(n):
    sp = [n]
    if n < 1:
        return []
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        else:
            n = 3 * n + 1 
        sp.append(n)
    for i in sp:
        print(i, end = ' ')

col(int(input()))
```

Тест не проходил, потому что не считывались входные данные с помощью `input()` и не вызывалась функция `col()`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не могли бы вы объяснить последнюю строчку? мне важно понять.

Comment: @EmilAliyev `input()` получает введенную строку (в данном случае это была строка "17", на сайте "Sample Input 1"), `int()` преобразует её в целочисленный тип.

Comment: Просто я впервые вижу изменение типа объекта уже вне функции. В коде n вела себя как целое число - сравнение, добавлялось в список как число (без кавычек). Я предполагал, что загвоздка где-то тут, но понять не мог. Значит, уже после объявления функции вместо аргумента нужно обозначить, что он был переведен в другой тип. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @EmilAliyev дело было в том, что не считывались входные данные и не вызывалась ваша функция

Comment: то есть, тест пытался дать функции строку "17", и поэтому она не вызывалась? Я давал функции число 17 в IDLE, да. И вы в конце явно указали, что аргумент нужно из строки перевести в число. Понял.

Comment: @EmilAliyev тест давал строку 17, а ваш скрипт её не считывал и результат теста выходил пустым, т.к. функция не вызывалась и в неё ничего не передавалось