# Минимальное количество перемещений по двухмерному пространству

Tags: c++, алгоритм, очередь

Даны координаты начала движения и координаты конца движения. Необходимо найти минимальное количество перемещений из начальной точки `(x1,y1)` в конечную `(x2,y2)`.  Пространство размером 8×8. Нельзя выходить за пределы. Перемещаться можно на одно деление вверх, вниз, вправо, влево и по диагоналям.
Например

```
8 1
2 1

Ответ 7
```

Comment: Судя по вашей постановке задачи, достаточно написать `int main(){cout<<"0\n";}`. Минимальное количество перемещений - 0 :) Вы же абсолютно ничего не пишете, что за перемещения, что во входных данных, что за алгоритм - и чего-то хотите?

Comment: @Harry исправила условие

Comment: Почему 7? Чтоб переместится из (2,1) в (1,1) надо одно перемещение => из (8,1) в (2, 1) надо 6 перемещений. Не заю зачем там столько кода, задача решается математически: max(|x1-x2|, |y1-y2|)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зачем [просто](https://ideone.com/FHTObd), если можно сложно? :)

Абсолютное (по модулю) смещение по x - dx, по y - dy. Выбираем большее, выводим.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int start_x, start_y, finish_x, finish_y;
    cin >> start_x>> start_y >> finish_x >> finish_y;
    cout << max(abs(start_x-finish_x),abs(start_y-finish_y)) << endl;
}
```

P.S. А живуча [старушка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/660924/195342) :) - то-то мне код показался знакомым... Это вы оттуда брали и самостоятельно меняли? или в другом месте? просто интересно, как автору :)

Comment: Да этот код от туда)