# Улучшить алгоритм нахождения числа

Tags: java, алгоритм

Передо мной стоит задача - получить из единицы вводимое пользователем число (не более 10^6), используя либо умножение на 2, либо умножение на 3, либо инкремент, при этом число операций должно быть минимальным. Написанный мной алгоритм решает задачу "с конца" и пробное число 32718 получает за 19 операций, однако по условию известно, что минимальное число операций - 17. Подскажите, как можно улучшить данный алгоритм, чтобы он мог выбирать, когда выгоднее умножить на два, а когда - на три?

```
public class Main {

static int n = 32718; // к этому числу необходимо прийти
static int n1;
static int start = 1; // начальное число
static int counter = 0;
static int[] operations = new int[30]; // массив, в который записываются результаты вычислений

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println(n);
    operations[counter] = n;
    while (n > start) {
        n1 = n-1;
        if (n % 3 == 0) {  // проверка кратности трем
            n /= 3;
            operations[counter] = n;
            counter++;
        }
        else if(n1 % 3 == 0) // проверка числа н-1 кратности трем
        {
            n--;
            operations[counter] = n;
            counter++;
            n /= 3;
            operations[counter] = n;
            counter++;
        }
        else if (n % 2 == 0) { // проверка кратности двум
            n /= 2;
            operations[counter] = n;
            counter++;
        }
        else { // декремент
                n--;
                operations[counter] = n;
                counter++;
            }
    }
        System.out.println(counter);
       for (int i = operations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // вывод исходного числа и промежуточных чисел в обр. порядке
            System.out.print(operations[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Намекаю: поиск в ширину... Вот, посмотрите, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660904/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f) ну очень похожая задача...

Comment: Кстати, "умножение на 2, на 3 и инкремент" - это три разные операции? две? Сформулируйте точнее - это `2*x`, `3*x`, `x+1` или какой набор операций? А, просчитал - судя по всему, это именно 3 операции.

Comment: @Harry три разные операции, поправил в вопросе.

Comment: Да, я уже просчитал - 1  2  4  8  24  25  50  150  151  453  454  1362  1363  2726  5452  5453  10906  32718

Comment: https://ideone.com/4ERebl

Comment: @Harry в задаче в качестве примера вывода для этого предлагалось следующее:
17
1 3 9 27 28 84 85 170 340 680 681 1362 1363 2726 5452 5453 16359 32718 
Видимо, можно пройти еще эффективнее, если чаще использовать умножение на 3 при вычислениях...

Comment: @МихайлоПащенко Если чаще использовать умножение на 3 при вычислениях, то можно перейти в состояние, когда вычесленное значение превышает требуемый результат. И тогда нужно возвращаться к предыдущим вариантам.

Comment: Эффективнее не будет, алгоритм не позволяет :) Просто решение - **не** единственное.

Comment: Это задача на `backtracking`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант решения через динамическое программирование.
Сложность по времени и по памяти O(n).
Дает ответ из 17 шагов на ваш пример.

```
public void test() {
    int n = 32718;
    int[] table = new int[1000000];
    table[0] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    table[1] = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        int i1 = i - 1;
        int i2 = i % 2 == 0 ? i / 2 : 0;
        int i3 = i % 3 == 0 ? i / 3 : 0;
        table[i] = 1 + min(table[i1], table[i2], table[i3]);
    }
    int minSteps = table[n];
    System.out.println("Steps: " + minSteps);

    // Выводим решение с конца
    int curValue = n;
    while (curValue >= 1) {
        System.out.println(curValue);
        int v1 = curValue - 1;
        int v2 = curValue % 2 == 0 ? curValue / 2 : 0;
        int v3 = curValue % 3 == 0 ? curValue / 3 : 0;
        if (table[v1] == table[curValue] - 1) {
            curValue = v1;
        } else if (table[v2] == table[curValue] - 1) {
            curValue = v2;
        } else {
            curValue = v3;
        }
    }
}

private int min(int a, int b, int c) {
    int minab = (a < b ? a : b);
    return minab < c ? minab : c;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Steps: 17
132718
132717
44239
44238
22119
7373
7372
7371
2457
819
273
91
90
30
10
9
3
1
```