# Как набрать Н очков используя умножение и сложение?

Tags: математика, графы, динамическое-программирование

Как решается данная задача?

> Машина в которую нужно кидать монеты.
>   10 копеек - результат умножается на 3;
>   5 копеек - + 4 к результату;
>   до начала на дисплее 1 очко
>   Нужно набрать 109 очков.

Comment: Нечто похожее спрашивали тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660904/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f У вас просто есть два других действия - +4 и *3. Можете посмотреть мой ответ и набросать свой - поиском в ширину в строящемся на лету графе...

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к методу решения с графами вот [решение динамическим программированием](https://ideone.com/qLOhzb).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

map<int,int> pr;

int getSol(int N, int start, map<int,int>& p)
{
    static array<int,2000> m = { 0 }; // Можно использовать map - тогда не нужен размер,
                                      // vector - в общем, что удобнее...

    if (N == start) { p[N] = 0; return 0; }
    if (N < start) return -1;  // Не туда попали :)

    if (m[N]) return m[N];

    int step = -1;
    if (N%3 == 0)
        step = getSol(N/3,start,p);
    int four = -1;
    if (N >= start+4)
        four = getSol(N-4,start,p);

    if (step < 0)
    {
        if (four < 0) return -1;
        pr[N] = N-4;
        return m[N] = four + 1;
    }
    if (four < 0 || step < four)
    {
        pr[N] = N/3;
        return m[N] = step + 1;
    }
    pr[N] = N-4;
    return m[N] = four + 1;
}

void print(map<int,int>&p, int n)        // Вывод пути в обратном порядке
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    print(p,p[n]);
    cout << n << "  ";
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << getSol(109,1,pr) << endl;   // Количество шагов

    print(pr,109);                      // Какие именно шаги

    cout << "\n";

}
```

Должен предупредить - для больших значений будет активно съедать стек. Так что либо надо этот код разворачивать в итеративный или восходящий подход ДП, или таки смотреть в сторону графов...

Answer (score 0):

Набросал решение с поиском в длину.

Суть решения в рекурсивном поиске ответа с попутной записью используемых монет.

```js
const getSol = (n) => {
  const req = (sum = 1, res = []) => {
    if (sum === n) return res;
    if (sum > n) return null;
    return req(sum + 4, [...res].concat(5)) || req(sum * 3, [...res].concat(10));
  }
  return req();
}
console.log(getSol(109));
```

Это решение подойдет если нужно найти любой ответ, но он может не быть кратчайшим или оптимальным по номиналу монет. Но у вас в условии такого не сказано.